# C++ lambda capture result

Tags: c++, lambda

For example I have next code:

```
int func() 
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    auto lambda{[&](){ return i; }};
    return lambda();
}
```

Will be `j` captured also by reference or lambda captures only objects that it uses?

Comment: How would one be able to tell the difference? Asking for a friend.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. sizeof: https://godbolt.org/z/QWWCZ5

Comment: @khuttun The standard does not provide any guarantees about sizeof of lambdas. [Neither do implementations](https://godbolt.org/z/TVVtJS).

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Good point. In your example the lambdas don't actually capture anything, though (because of the `const`).

Comment: @khuttun I think formally the variables are still captured and then the compiler optimises them away. Const was the easiest way to cause this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `j` won't be captured

From [Lambda capture](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) docs:

> & (implicitly capture the ***used*** automatic variables by reference)

Note the word *"used"*

Answer (score 4):

No, `j` will not be captured.

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda:

> The captures is a comma-separated list of zero or more captures,
>   optionally beginning with the capture-default. The only capture
>   defaults are
>
> - & (implicitly capture the used automatic variables by reference) and
> - = (implicitly capture the used automatic variables by copy).